# Calculate the vertical asymptote of the absolute of a complex rational function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function with the following shape:

$$
f(x) = \left|\frac{a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n}{b_0 + b_1x+b_2x^2 + ... + b_nx^n} \right|
$$
The constant $b_0=1$ (I don know if it matters)

When the function is plotted with an example set of values:

> a: $$\begin{array}{rcccl} [ & 1.007619-0.003295j & -0.705018+0.005862j & 0.180197-0.002728j &\\  & -0.020212+0.000541j & 0.000905-0.000053j &-0.000007+0.000003j&] \end{array}$$
>
> b: $$\begin{array}{rcccl} [ & 1.000000+0.j & -0.651524+0.039991j & 0.149934-0.023741j \\ & -0.014107+0.004824j & 0.000419-0.000381j & 0.000004+0.000009j &]\end{array}$$

The resulting plot is:
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ILuT.png)

The function represents the voltage collapse of a function up to the asymptote at $x=4$. and the values for $x>4$ are meaningless, therefore I would like to know how to compute the asymptotic value of the general function, which in this case happens to be 4 by visual inspection.

Comment: Find the zeros of the denominator, and make sure they are not also zeros of the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Molokach mentions, the asymptotes occur where the denominator is zero, but the numerator is not. They can also occur when both are 0, but testing for this will require additional steps.

So how do you find zeros of the denominator? Since this is not some nice neat controlled polynomial where factoring or special tricks might provide an answer, you will need to use a root-finder. Matlab and Mathematica both have them. [I plugged your example equation above into Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?lk=3&i=1%20%2B%28%E2%88%920.651524%2B0.039991i%29z%20%2B%20%280.149934-0.023741i%29z%5E2%20%2B%20%28-0.014107%2B0.004824i%29z%5E3%20%2B%20%280.000419-0.000381i%29z%5E4%20%2B%20%280.000004%2B0.000009i%29z%5E5%20%3D%200) (be careful - Wolfram Alpha only recognizes $i$ as the complex unit, not $j$) and got these approximate roots:
$$z_1 = -10.4829+52.2147 i\\
z_2 = 4.09556+0.0106803 i\\
z_3 = 4.8545+0.0847305 i\\
z_4 = 8.35268+0.00964223 i\\
z_5 = 11.2523+2.26783 i$$

(I got this from using "solve *polynomial* = $0$", but if you find yourself with fewer roots than the degree of the polynomial, you will want use "factor *polynomial*" instead. By looking at the factors, you can see which roots are repeated.)

$z_2$ is the actual value for your root from inspection. You can also see signs of $z_3$ in the graph, but since it is a little farther from the real axis, it isn't as evident.

The next thing you need to do is check that the numerator is not also zero at any of the values. Finding the roots of the numerator gives:
$$w_1 = 4.15897+0.138549 i\\
w_2 = 4.47753-0.212926 i\\
w_3 = 7.68335+1.68409 i\\
w_4 = 9.13958-2.26771 i\\
w_5 = 86.5061+41.0718 i$$

$w_1$ and $w_2$ are close to $z_2$ and $z_3$. Whether these could be considered shared roots depends on how accurate your coefficients are. I'll assume that the accuracy is roughly the number of digits you provided. In that case, we are probably safe in saying that the roots are not the same. Thus your example function has 5 asymptotes at $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5$.

If both numerator and denominator share a root, look at how many times the root is repeated for the numerator and for the denominator. If the denominator has more repetitions than the numerator, then the root is still an asymptote. Otherwise it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried that before asking the question but the root finders I used give me this result:   -0.18167 + 0.60338i
  -0.18167 - 0.60338i
   0.17425 + 0.59324i
   0.17425 - 0.59324i
  -0.00006 + 0.00000i
I cannot reproduce your outcome, neither with python or octave or wolfram alpha

Comment: Mayhap we are interpreting your list of coefficients in a different order. I took the first one to be $a_0$, and the right most to be $a_5$, and similarly for the $b$ coefficients.

Comment: I added a link to the actual equation I entered in Wolfram Alpha, so you can check to see if I had it right (just above where I showed the roots). However, since my roots explain your graph whereas yours do not, I have to believe that you made an error when you entered the equation.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is on me to guess why the python polynomial roots solver does not find those results. Also I learned a bit more about wolfram alpha